# Android - Problem with ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution, but could not find any. I'm almost certain that it will look like a dummy question to some of you, but I'm really stuck here.

I'm trying to have a MapActivity with a 5 rows ListView at the top of the screen, followed by a MapView. The ListView will always be 5 rows big.

I'm using this layout, which gave me the closest of the result I want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/infoListe"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
          android:id="@+id/mapview"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="200dip"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:apiKey="<KEY_OMITTED_HERE>"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I get the result I want on recent hi-res devices, but on lower resolution devices, the ListView and the MapView do overlap on the screen.

I would like your help to understand how to add a ScrollView to the layout so that I get a scrollable solution presenting : 
1/ the 5 rows ListView 
2/ the MapView

If the screen is to small, the user can scroll to get to the MapView section.

Thank you to anyone who will take a few minutes to help me. All my tests have failed so far.

Adam.

Comment: Quick question before I try reproducing this: have you tried replacing that RelativeLayout with a ScrollView? Is that when the MapView starts to overlap the ListView?

Comment: Hello Hydrangea. Yes I basically tried to do that, and also tried the various solutions I could parse on the web (LinearLayout > Scroll > Relative). I've also tried to change the layout types with no success. For the moment, I'll go with the workaround provided by Ravi below. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this workaround : [ListView in ScrollView potential workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097385/listview-in-scrollview-potential-workaround/4115382#4115382)

Basically try putting your map into the footerview of the listview to prevent them from overlapping.

Comment: Ravi : 1 last question refering to the workaround that you provided to me. How can I set the height of the footer? Let's say that I want it to have a height of 200dip ? Thanks again.

Comment: You can set the hight of the footer layout , in your case the hight of the mapview

Comment: Ravi : I don't seem to be able to set the height, although I m using the following code to describe my mapview :
`<com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="200dip" 
     android:enabled="true"
     android:clickable="false"
     android:apiKey="OMITTED"/> `