# Prevent ListView from scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, footer

I have a scrollview with a linear layout in it. Within that linear layout there is a list view. The problem I am having is that my list view only has a certain amount of space and then becomes scrollable. I don't want this to happen. I want the entire list to be shown. Does anyone know how I might achieve this? I have tried using this link however my layout does not appear when I add the footer. [ListView in ScrollView potential workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097385/listview-in-scrollview-potential-workaround) This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/darkimg"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/numbersLL"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rectangle"
        android:layout_margin="4px"
        android:paddingLeft="6px"
        android:paddingTop="3px">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberPrint"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/numberPrint">
        </TextView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/numberListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my footer:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/formLL">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberFormTextViewt"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:text="Add a number:"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/numberFormButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Java code to add the footer to the list:

```
        LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout numberFooter = (LinearLayout) factory.inflate(R.layout.number_form, null);
        // List of numbers
        numberListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.numberListView);
        numberListView.addFooterView(numberFooter);
```

What is going wrong here? The footer does not appear when the activity is displayed. One thing I should mention is the footer is used to add items to the list above it. I'm not sure if that makes a difference but when I am testing this the list adapter is empty. Even still should the footer show up anyway? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This [LInk](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/
) has perfect example just take a look....

also checkout this Question...[amongst us](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121186/android-listview-with-header-and-footer-buttons)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure this will help me though as I am attempting to have several ListViews with different footers.

Comment: Wait I see the height of the List is 0dp so it might work. Not used to relative Layouts but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Let me know so I can post it as answer...

Comment: I am going to do this an entirely different way. From more research I've realised using a ListView in a scrollview is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your listview:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: I've already tried that it doesn't work. The list will continue to scroll. The workaround from the other post seems like the solution for me but my footer won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

List view under scroll view is not working(means List view is not scrollable).

So u can put empty Linear Layout instead of List view in ur xml file. In ur code, first u can get the list view size, based on this size value, for loop can rotated. In that for loop  u can call the get view method of the adapter class(that class is not extending any class.)  this will solve the list view problem.